# how do i write a firestore rules where another user can only update one variables of other users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How do I write a Firestore rules where another user can only update one  variable of other users?

use case 1: I have a collection called users and users can edit their own data, this is a normal.

use case 2: user1 can edit user2 data but only 1 variable called impactCount.

Should I allow user1 to edit one of user2 variable or should I create another collection called impact collection which has userId and impactCount, so that user1 can edit the impactCount there and user2 can get the data from impact collection

This is currently what I have:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function updateComTask(varName) {
        return request.auth != null && 
        request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).changedKeys().hasOnly([varName])
    }
    
    match /userTasks/{userID} {
      allow create, read, update: 
        if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userID;
      allow delete: 
        if request.auth != null && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).changedKeys().hasOnly(["tasks"]);
    }
    
    match /communityTasks/{taskID} {
      allow create, read: if request.auth != null;
      allow update: 
        if updateComTask("addCount") && 
        request.resource.data.addCount == resource.data.addCount + 1;
      allow update: 
        if updateComTask("doneCount") && 
        request.resource.data.doneCount == resource.data.doneCount + 1;
      allow delete: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're hoping to accomplish.  Could you edit the question and provide a more specific examples of actual queries that should be allowed or denied by these rules, and say more about what currently isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: i just update the question. is it clearer?

Comment: The syntax seems to be valid. What problem are you facing implementing this rules?

Comment: i am facing user1 are not allow to edit impactCount of user2, which I wanted.

Comment: anyone knows @DougStevenson @vitooh?

Comment: You should provide samples of code that perform the queries that aren't working the way you expect.  There should be enough information in your question that anyone can easily reproduce the issue.